# Determine expression values for a defined list of genes across different clusters in scRNA data using seurat

Tags: scrnaseq, seurat, gene-expression

I am analyzing publically available scRNA seq datasets on R using Seurat. I have created a seurat object, clustered and annotated different cell types. Now, I am interested in comparing the expression values and percentage of expressing cells within each cluster for a given set of genes I am interested in. I can  visualize their expression using DotPlots, feature plots, etc... but how can I generate a table with the expression values (log2FC) for my defined set of genes across the different clusters/cell types?
Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please clarify more precisely what you want, as there is inconsistency in your question. `log2FC` values are log-transformed fold change values, and represent a *change* between two expression profiles, i.e. they represent *differential* expression, not expression.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're looking for *differential* expression values, the `FindMarkers` function within Seurat would be a good thing to try first:

```
# find all markers distinguishing cluster 5 from clusters 0 and 3
cluster5.markers <- FindMarkers(pbmc, ident.1 = 5, ident.2 = c(0, 3), min.pct = 0.25)
head(cluster5.markers, n = 5)
##                       p_val avg_log2FC pct.1 pct.2     p_val_adj
## FCGR3A        8.246578e-205   4.261495 0.975 0.040 1.130936e-200
## IFITM3        1.677613e-195   3.879339 0.975 0.049 2.300678e-191
## CFD           2.401156e-193   3.405492 0.938 0.038 3.292945e-189
## CD68          2.900384e-191   3.020484 0.926 0.035 3.977587e-187
## RP11-290F20.3 2.513244e-186   2.720057 0.840 0.017 3.446663e-182
```

[Note the `avg_log2FC` column]

More details can be found at the bottom of the Seurat tutorial pages for the PBMC 3K Guided Tutorial, *Finding differentially expressed features (cluster biomarkers)*:

https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/pbmc3k_tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks you very much! Yes, that is what I was looking for. I also found the AverageExpression function to look at expression values across clusters